# Texture doesn't cover the whole Sphere Geometry in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

[clik here to see picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYDxv.png)
I want to make rotated moon. Everything works fine with MeshStandardMaterial(with color but without using texture) but when I apply texture on sphere geometry. its working but it behaves abnormally. the problem is "texture does not cover the entire body of sphere".

this is my code snippet:

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls"
import moonImage from "../../images/moon.jpg"
const Home = () => {

   useEffect(() => {

    const scene=new THREE.Scene();

    const camera=new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75,window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,1,1000);

    const canvas=document.querySelector(".homeCanvas");

    const renderer=new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

    const textureLoader=new THREE.TextureLoader();

    const moonTexture= textureLoader.load(moonImage);
   
    const moonGeo=new THREE.SphereGeometry(3,64,64);

    const moonMaterial=new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({map:moonTexture});
   
    const moon=new THREE.Mesh(moonGeo,moonMaterial);

    scene.add(moon);
    
    const pointLight=new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff,1);
    pointLight.position.x=20;
    scene.add(pointLight);
    
    const controls=new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
    
    camera.position.z=15;

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        moom.rotation.x+=0.01;
        moon.rotation.y+=0.01;
        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        
    }
    animate();

    
  }, []);

   
  return (
   <>
   <div className="home"> 
    <canvas className="homeCanvas"></canvas>
   </div>
   </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moon is partially visible since the point light only illuminates one side. You can avoid such issues by adding any sort of indirect, environmental light to the scene. This could be an environment map or even simpler an instance of `THREE.AmbientLight` like in the following live example:

```js
const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1000);

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
  antialias: true
});
renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

const moonTexture = textureLoader.load('https://threejs.org/examples/textures/uv_grid_opengl.jpg');

const moonGeo = new THREE.SphereGeometry(3, 64, 64);

const moonMaterial = new THREE.MeshStandardMaterial({
  map: moonTexture
});

const moon = new THREE.Mesh(moonGeo, moonMaterial);

scene.add(moon);

const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
pointLight.position.x = 20;
scene.add(pointLight);

const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff, 0.6)
scene.add(ambientLight);

camera.position.z = 15;

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  
  moon.rotation.x += 0.01;
  moon.rotation.y += 0.01;
  
  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
animate();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.146/build/three.min.js"></script>
```